# Outlook customisation addin

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I want to know if there are ways to customise the outlook (2013) mail exchange client.  Ultimately, I want to, if possible, have an extra field when viewing the mail, e.g. after received time, a field called 'category'.. user selects from dropdown, sales or other.  Ultimate I'd want to be able to add the value to the extended property of the mailitem object.  I have experience using Exchange Web Services and coding in C# and Java but have no idea if the above is possible (custoomising the outlook interface, not just menu customisation) and if so what languages/tool are best used.

Any suggestions apopreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do that. But you can use built-in Outlook categories (which you can extend by adding your own ones).

Comment: Hi Dimitry

I want to be able to see extra field in the window pane.  E.g From, Received, NewField.  And be able to assign a value to NewField.

Comment: You cannot add a control to that area. If it is either a ribbon control or a form region just below the From/Received/etc. pane.